# classification report using YellowBrick

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, yellowbrick

i recently implemented Probabilistic Neural Network on the iris dataset. i was trying to print classification report using YellowBrick classifier but when i run this code i get an error. which is as following.

```
from neupy import algorithms
model = algorithms.PNN(std=0.1, verbose=True, batch_size = 500)
model.train(X_train, Y_train)
predictions = model.predict(X_test)


from yellowbrick.classifier import ClassificationReport
visualizer = ClassificationReport(model, support=True)

visualizer.fit(X_train, Y_train)  # Fit the visualizer and the model
visualizer.score(X_test, Y_test)  # Evaluate the model on the test data
visualizer.show()
```

this code returns this error.

```
YellowbrickTypeError: This estimator is not a classifier; try a regression or clustering score visualizer instead!
```

when i tried the same classification report code for other classification  model it works. i have no idea. why is this happening? can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Please show what exactly your `model` is.

Comment: hi @desertnaut.. i have added it. im sorry for not adding it earlier

Answer (score 5):

Yellowbrick is intended to be used with scikit-learn and uses sklearn's type checking system to detect if a model fits a particular class of machine learning problem. If the neupy `PNN` model implements the scikit-learn estimator API (e.g. `fit()` and `predict()`) - it may be possible to directly use the model and bypass the type checking by using the `force_model=True` parameter as follows:

```
visualizer = ClassificationReport(model, support=True, force_model=True)
```

However, after taking a quick glance at the [neupy documentation](http://neupy.com/modules/generated/neupy.algorithms.PNN.html#neupy.algorithms.PNN) it appears that this won't necessarily work since the neupy method is named `train` and not `fit` and because the PNN model does not implement a `score()` method nor have support for `_` suffixed learned parameters.

The solution is to create a light-weight wrapper that surrounds the `PNN` model that exposes it as a sklearn estimator. Testing on a Yellowbrick dataset, this appears to work:

```
from sklearn import metrics
from neupy import algorithms
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator
from yellowbrick.datasets import load_occupancy
from yellowbrick.classifier import ClassificationReport
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


class PNNWrapper(algorithms.PNN, BaseEstimator):
    """
    The PNN wrapper implements BaseEstimator and allows the classification
    report to score the model and understand the learned classes.
    """

    @property
    def classes_(self):
        return self.classes

    def score(self, X_test, y_test):
        y_hat = self.predict(X_test)
        return metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_hat)


# Load the binary classification dataset 
X, y = load_occupancy()
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

# Create and train the PNN model using the sklearn wrapper
model = PNNWrapper(std=0.1, verbose=True, batch_size=500)
model.train(X_train, y_train)

# Create the classification report
viz = ClassificationReport(
    model, 
    support=True, 
    classes=["not occupied", "occupied"], 
    is_fitted=True, 
    force_model=True, 
    title="PNN"
)

# Score the report and show it
viz.score(X_test, y_test)
viz.show()
```

Although neupy is not currently supported by Yellowbrick, if you're interested - it might be worth [submitting an issue](https://github.com/DistrictDataLabs/yellowbrick/issues) suggesting that neupy be added to contrib, similar to how `statsmodels` is implemented in Yellowbrick.

Comment: Can you please guide me on how to use yellowbrick for xgb.train() models? I am fairly new to this module and cannot make it work for my XGB model